# Metatranscriptomics Extraction

Tags: rna-sequencing

I am attempting to perform metatranscriptomics analysis of a cleanroom. The DNA input is known to be rather low (<1pg). Despite this, I want to still attempt to try it. I am thinking it might be best to perform extraction trials before hand where certain parameters are manipulated. I can then determine from these extraction trials which values for which parameters are best.

As an example, I am reading a peer-reviewed paper called "Validation of picogram- and femtogram-input DNA libraries for microscale metagenomics" where they used the Illumina Nextera XT DNA library preparation kit on low biomass samples. Two of the parameters they manipulated were:

1) PCR cycle numbers (Values = 12, 14, 16, 18, 20) 
2) ATM dilution (Values = undiluted, 1:5, 1:10, 1:20, 1:50)

I am hoping to use the same type of extraction trials to determine which combination of values from these two parameters is best for a clean room. **My first question is:** How can I determine which combination is best (as there are 25 combinations)? I have two ideas (but am open to others):

1) Check the amount of RNA derived
2) Check some quality metric on RNA

As I hope to do triplets of each of the 25 combinations, I will have 75 samples. I am hoping not to have to do sequencing as it is time consuming and possibly expensive in order to chose the best combination. Is there a way to chose which combination works best without having to sequence?

**My second question is:** Are there any other parameters in this workflow that I can also test for if I am not getting decent results in these low-biomass cleanrooms?

(As you can tell, I do not have too much direct molecular biology experience, so feel free to correct or question any of my post and/or "dumb down" your response). Thank you for sharing advice (for either question)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Consider doing triplicates of just 4 combinations of cycle/dilution: low+low, low+high, high+ low, high+high.  Simpler.
2. Most important: **prove you can extract DNA from a clean room.**  If you extract from a real clean room and get no result from the PCR, maybe it is because you failed to collect anything or maybe nothing was there.   Idea - spray a known quantity of DNA into a room that will serve as your sham clean room.  Then do your extraction protocol.  You can test the cycle / dilution parameters with the sham clean room extraction and have those variables optimized for when you collect from a real "wild" clean room you did not dope with DNA.